# My component does not react to change Vue with Vuex

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex

I have a state in the Vuex store that reacts to the change in the button and everything changes its dependent value, the problem is that I am using it in a component and I call it in the data()

```
data() {
    return {
      currency: this.$store.state.currency,
    }
}
```

When mounting the component, everything is displayed fine, because it takes the value from storage, but when I update that value, the change is not reflected in the component.
I would like to know how I could make the variable render again with the new value of the storage, every time it changes.

I tried using the currency variable where I save the data, it did not work and I also tried to place the variable directly where it is used, but it did not work either

Comment: Don't use it in data if you want it to be reactive. It should be wrapped with a computed or mapped with mapState

Comment: Could you make a clearer example and if it works close the question, thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
computed: {
  currency() {
    return this.$store.state.currency;
  },
},
```

Do it like that.

Comment: Better to use mapState instead of calling it directly by this.$store.state